# Unable to sort List

Tags: c#, sorting, interface

I want to sort a field that is a list of events, based on one of its fields - its timestamp. But I'm getting an error that the field is not defined in the interface that it implements.

```
// Outer class
public void SortEvents()
{
     _events = _events.OrderByDescending((shipmentEvent) => shipmentEvent._timestamp).ToList();
}

private class Event : IShipmentEvent
{
     public readonly DateTime _timestamp;
     public readonly string    _location;
     public readonly string _description;

     public Event(DateTime timestamp, string location, string description)
     {
           _timestamp   =   timestamp;
           _location    =    location;
           _description = description;
     }
}
```

> 'IShipmentEvent' does not contain a definition for '_timestamp' and no
>   extension method '_timestamp' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IShipmentEvent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

I tried typehinting `(Event shipmentEvent)` in the argument list of the lambda expression but then I got the error:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for
>   'OrderByDescending' and the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.OrderByDescending(IQueryable, Expression>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

The interface is just a dummy interface that allows me to expose the list of  private class objects outside the implementing class:

```
public interface IShipmentEvent {}

...

private List<IShipmentEvent> _events;

public List<IShipmentEvent> Events { get { return _events; } }
```

Comment: what is the type of `_events` and how is `IShipmentEvent` defined?

Comment: You are trying to sort a list of `IShipmentEvents`? What does `IShipmentEvent` look like? Does it contain a `_timestamp` property?

Comment: @SimonC See my updated question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by casting the parameter to an Event type. So simple I'm surprised I didn't come to think of it sooner:

> (**(Event)** shipmentEvent)._timestamp

```
_events = _events.OrderByDescending((shipmentEvent) => ((Event)shipmentEvent)._timestamp).ToList();
```

Comment: That’s likely to break because—as I said—the list can contain non-Event objects. And if it can’t, you should change the type of the list to reflect that.

Comment: I can't change the list to <Event> because that won't allow me to expose it outside the class. It will **always** contain Event objects.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Event` contains `_timestamp` **not** the interface `IShipmentEvent`.  Add `_timestamp` to the interface.

Comment: Problem is, `_timestamp` is a field, not a property and AFAIK fields are not allowed in interfaces. Prove me if I'm wrong, though!

Comment: @silkfire That is correct but you could easily make it a readonly property then. Which is better anyway for apublic interface.

Comment: @poke Thanks. I came up with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

`_events` is a list of `IShipmentEvent` objects. As such, it is not guaranteed that every object in the list is an `Event` which has the `_timestamp` field. It’s just as possible that there is another type that implements `IShipmentEvent` but does not have that field, and objects of that type are also present in the list.

If you want to make sure that you can access `_timestamp`, either change the list type to `List<Event>` so it can take only `Event` objects, or add the `_timestamp` field to the interface to make all `IShipmentEvent` objects have it.